# How is getAdaptoer used with this simple class for SQlite data retrieval and storage?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, oop

I'm using an SQLite database in my Android App.  I've extrapolated my code from a particular website which I can't seem to locate now.  But the code includes a class for stuffing and retrieving a SQLite data row:  I call the class dbData. As far as I can tell, it simply stores the data row.  There is no constructor, so apparently it creates an instance of the adapter when called using the default.  The tostring is returned as dbData. But an Id can be set and gotten too.

My big question is why use this class instead of variables within the other classes that otherwise call this class?  My next question is, if the listAdaptor returns the adaptor (per http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#getAdapter()) what information does it stuff into dbData in the line dbData = (dbData) lstView.getAdapter().getItem(0); that it allows dbData to return a string and grab the correct database row?  Is it automatically converting the adapter to the database key field?

Thanks for any feedback.

Here's the code:

```
public class dbData {

    private long id;
    private String dbData;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDbData() {
        return dbData;
    }

    public void setDbData(String dbData) {
        this.dbData = dbData;
    }

    // Will be used by the ArrayAdapter in the ListView
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return dbData;
    }

}
```

Here is an example of how it is called:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

    ListView lstView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lstHolidays);

    ArrayAdapter<dbData> adapter = (ArrayAdapter<dbData>) lstView.getAdapter();
    dbData dbData = null;
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.add:
            String[] comments = new String[] { "Cool", "Very nice", "Hate it" };
            int nextInt = new Random().nextInt(3);
            // save the new dbData to the database
            dbData = datasource.createDB_Row(comments[nextInt]);
            adapter.add(dbData);
            break;
        case R.id.delete:
            if (lstView.getAdapter().getCount() > 0) {
                dbData = (dbData) lstView.getAdapter().getItem(0);
                datasource.deleteDB_Row(dbData);
                adapter.remove(dbData);
            }
            break;
    }
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: The code you posted doesn't seem to do any of those things?

Comment: I fumbled through my explanation a little.  simplified the first paragraph.  Does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several questions here, as you said.

1. Why use `dbData`? Answer: Because it makes it possible to do things with the database rows. In this:

   ```
   dbData = (dbData) lstView.getAdapter().getItem(0);
   ```

   what would you do if there was no `dbData` class? You'd probably have to do this:

   ```
   dbData_id = (Long) lstView.getAdapter().getItem(0).getItem(0);
   dbData_dbData = (String) lstView.getAdapter().getItem(0).getItem(1);
   ```

   Now imagine doing that if there were 20 or 30 fields in the database.
2. What information does the line `dbData = (dbData) lstView.getAdapter().getItem(0);` stuff into `dbData`?

   This makes `dbData` (the variable) contain a reference to a `dbData` object. Since you're using an `ArrayAdapter`, this reference came from the array. No database magic here, just an array access.
3. Is it automatically converting the adapter to the database key field?

   I don't know what you mean. No, it just gets an element from an array (which is hidden inside the `ArrayAdapter`).
4. Is the line `ArrayAdapter<dbData> adapter = (ArrayAdapter<dbData>) lstView.getAdapter();` important since it's not used?

   It is used. Look several lines below that, and you see `adapter.add(dbData);`. And `adapter.remove(dbData);`, and `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`.

Comment: Thanks. caught my mistake you mention under item 4.  Regarding number 3, My question might be better stated as "What is the element its getting from the array (an adaptor?) and how is that converted to a database row for dbData?"  Put another way, how does it know how to return Id of the dbData row with dbData.getID() by simply grabbing the adapter from the listView.  The code has implementations for getID, in the deletDB_Row method, but nowhere does it use setID.

Comment: @EdwardBagby at some point in the past your code added all the rows to the adapter (which stored them internally in an array).

Comment: I appreciate you continuing to respond.  I think this might be an OOP thing I am unfamiliar with --possibly because this is Java and not .net, but I think I better isolated my question, and it goes to your point in your answer "1" above.  So let me ask this way, when lstView.getAdapter().getItem(0); is passed to dbData, does the dbData class know to automatically populate private long id; and private String dbData; with the values (item & subItem) from the list View via the Adapter?

Comment: `lstView.getAdapter().getItem(0)` is not "passed to `dbData`". `(dbData)` is a *cast*.

Comment: Light bulb turned on.  Thanks.

Comment: @EdwardBagby and (to avoid possible confusion) remember it's casting the *reference*, not the object.